# Parallax USB RFID Raspberry Pi python doesnt read as if plugged in as keyboard

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, parallax, rfid

When I plug my Parallax RFID USB reader into usb port on Windows and scan a tag, I get 0004268206 But when I follow every's tutorials on reading RFID tags with this reader on a Raspberry Pi using python I get a totally different number. How can I get what I read via USB in Windows?

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400) 
while True:
    try:
        response = ser.read(12)
        print str(response)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

ser.close()
```

I get 2010E

Any ideas?

Comment: Try reading more than 12 bytes and see what the result is.

Comment: I changed ser.read(12) to ser.readline() I get 20040E Which is even different.

Comment: What if you do something like `ser.read(100)`?

Comment: I get a different number: 00420AE